# How do I create a temporary ZIP in Python 3.x using pyminizip?

Tags: python, temporary

I need to create a temporary zip file to store files. That ZIP file needs to be encrypted, so *zipfile* won't do the trick here. The file will be further encrypted (the ZIP will be encrypted again into another file), so zipping the file is used as a way of reducing its size for faster internet transmission as well as the first layer of encryption.
Here's what I've got so far:

```
import getpass
import tempfile
import pyminizip

def ZipFunction():
    #This zips the file and encrypts it with a password
    filename = input('Enter the file name: ')
    passkey = getpass.getpass(prompt='Enter the password for the file: ')
    passkey2 = getpass.getpass(prompt='Confirm the password: ')
    if passkey != passkey2:
        print('The passwords must be the same! Please restart the process.')
        exit()
    else:
        #Here's where I need help
        with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmp:
            with pyminizip.compress(filename,None,tmp,passkey,9) as archive:
                zipstring = archive.readlines()

        #From here on the zipstring var is encrypted and creates the "further encrypted"
        #file. From here on the script works normally
```

The error returned is `ValueError: expected arguments are compress(src, srcpath, dst, pass, level)`.
I'd be willing to change pyminizip to another tool that can create encrypted zip files. This "dual encryption layer" is a customer demand, and although I don't really think it's necessary, I don't have the authority to scrap it from the project.
I'm not used to dealing with Temporary Files. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: One thing that looks suspicious is that you're passing `None` as the `srcpath`.

Comment: Thanks martineau! Although this does appear weird, the same line used outside of this context creates a perfectly functional zip file. I've tried changing `None` to `os.getcwd()`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/tempfile.html)-module temporary files can be created which are automatically deleted when closing or leaving a [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)-block. With the [pyminizip](https://pypi.org/project/pyminizip/)-module encrypted zip-files can be obtained.

`pyminizip.compress` expects as third parameter the path where the generated zip-file should be saved. If a file is already there, an attempt is made to overwrite it. The current code uses the reference to the tempfile (`tmp`), which leads to the observed error message:

```
ValueError: expected arguments are compress(src, srcpath, dst, pass, level)
```

The direct cause of the error is that the reference itself and not its file name is used, i.e. to avoid the error, `tmp.name` should actually be used instead of `tmp`. However, if this is changed, a different error message is generated, namely

```
OSError: error in closing <path to temo file> (-102)
```

This is because the pyminizip-module tries to delete the tempfile while it is still open. If the tempfile were closed before, it would be overwritten without error message. However, this would only create a normal file and not a tempfile, i.e. the file wouldn't be deleted *automatically* when closing or leaving the `with`-block.

Thus, it is not possible to create temporary, encrypted zip-files with the tempfile- and pyminizip-module *in this way*. However, the tempfile-module allows the creation of temporary files as well as *temporary directories*. Like temporary files, temporary directories are deleted when leaving a `with`-block. If a temporary directory is deleted, the files contained therein are also deleted. Therefore an alternative would be common, encrypted zip-files (created with the pyminizip-module), which are stored in a temporary folder (created with the tempfile-module):

```
...
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tdir:
    sourceFile = <path to file to be zipped>
    destinationFile = "destFile.zip"
    password = "whatever"
    compression_level = 9 # 1-9
    pyminizip.compress(sourceFile, None, tdir + "\\" + destinationFile, password, compression_level)

    # inside with-block: temp-directory and contained encrypted zip-files exist
    ...                     

# outside with-block: temp-directory and contained encrypted zip-files deleted
...
```

If the `with`-block is left, the temporary directory is deleted along with any encrypted zip files it contains.

By the way: `pyminizip.compress` doesn't support a `with`-statement. This would cause the error message: `AttributeError: __enter__`. In the current code you can't see this error message, because the posted error message is triggered before.

Comment: This sounds great, but whenever I try to reference the destinationFile it returns an error ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'destFile.zip'```. I've tried using a different approach - ```zipfile = pyminizip.compress(sourceFile, None, tdir + "\\" + destinationFile, password, compression_level)```, but then it returns ```None``` whenever I try to fetch any data from the _zipfile_ var. Any ideas as to how can I read the created zip file as a string like in the 'original' code above?

Comment: (1) The zip-file must be accessed _within_ the `with`-block, otherwise the directory and its contents will already have been deleted. I paste my test program [here](https://pastebin.com/WpM6Fgnf). You have to change the path to the source file (`sourceFile = "C:/Test/src.txt"`). The generated zip-file will be accessed successfully within the `with`-block, after leaving the `with`-block the access fails. This works on my machine. (2) The approach `zipfile = pyminizip.compress(...` _must_ fail, because [`compress`](https://pypi.org/project/pyminizip/) returns always `None`.