# How to compress a file-like object with password and then upload it to s3 in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, file-io, zip

I want to export a dataframe to a .csv file, zip it, set a password to it, and then upload it to a public s3 bucket.

Since I am writing a serverless script, the I/O is a bit tricky, but I was able to write this code:

```
import gzip
import io
import boto3

gz_buffer = io.BytesIO()
report_bucket_public = "s3_bucket"
report_key_public = "s3_key"
df_report = pd.DataFrame(...)      # the data to upload

with gzip.GzipFile(mode='w', fileobj=gz_buffer) as gz_file:
    df_report.to_csv(io.TextIOWrapper(gz_file, 'utf8'), index=False)

s3_client = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_obj = s3_client.Object(report_bucket_public, report_key_public)
s3_obj.put(Body=gz_buffer.getvalue())
s3_client.ObjectAcl(report_bucket_public, report_key_public).put(ACL='public-read')
```

However, I'm unable to set a password to the .zip file. I tried to use the [pyminizip](https://pypi.org/project/pyminizip/) library, but I couldn't get it to work.

```
csv_stream =  io.BytesIO()
df_report.to_csv(io.TextIOWrapper(csv_stream, 'utf8'), index=False)

zip_stream =  io.BytesIO()
secret_password = "password"
compression_level = 5 

pyminizip.compress(
    csv_stream,
    None,
    zip_stream,
    secret_password, 
    compression_level
)
```

```
ValueError: expected arguments are compress(src, srcpath, dst, pass, level)
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by using `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()` and writing both the uncompressed and compressed data to files within the temporary directory.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59452759/9465722) to a related question.